# Exception handling with MVVM at the Model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

As a new person to WPF and the MVVM theory, **what is best practice for handling exceptions in the model that need to trigger a visual alert on the view?**

In my scenario I have a view, model and viewmodel. The view contains a hidden grid which will display when an exception occurs, this presents a friendly message in a textblock with a button to close the error message.

The viewmodel instructs the model to write some data to a file by calling the appropriate method in the model. If the write fails for whatever-reason, the model throws an exception.

This exception needs to trigger the view to display the hidden grid and populate the error message textblock.

**What is the best way to achieve this?**

My thoughts are: In my model I need to create a boolean property ‘ExceptionThrown’ and a string property ‘ErrorMessage’. The model will need to use the interface INotifyPropertyChanged and I will need to bind my hidden error grid to the ‘ExceptionThrown’ property somehow.  This way when the property ‘ExceptionThrown’ is changed, the ‘PropertyChangedEventHandler’ and view bindings will display the hidden grid and error message.

This approach feels wrong, over-complicated and limiting. What I really want to do is populate the error message and visibility of the hidden grid in the viewmodel when the exception is thrown in the model.

I have spent several hours looking at the best way to approach this, but I have not found anything that is definitive; I am very sure this has been answered in detail somewhere, I just haven’t found it.

Just looking for some good advice.

Comment: Why not just catch the exception in the view model and then do all the rest in the catch block inside the view model?

Comment: Bind the visibility of whatever control you want to use to display your errors to an observable string like 'ErrorContent' which will be set to exception text. When the user clears the string the visibility will change and the control disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I would separate the whole error displaying logic to its own ViewModel and View (UserControl or something) and send the errors with messaging to it.

With this you can send your errors to display from anywhere in your project and it'd be decoupled from anything else, you don't have to inject it everywhere where you want to use it, only the Messenger itself.

[Here](http://dotnetpattern.com/mvvm-light-messenger) is a messenger implementation you can use to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need exceptions to handle data validation. The better solution for WPF / MVVM applications is to use IDataErrorInfo.

1) Implement IDataErrorInfo on either your Model or ViewModel - depending on what you're actually binding to.

```
public class PersonModel: IDataErrorInfo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string this[string columnName]
    { 
        get 
        {
            var result = string.Empty;

            switch (columnName)
            {
                case nameof(Name):
                    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Name))
                        result = "Name is required";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2) Update your data binding to set ValidatesOnDataErrors.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Model.Name, 
                ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

By default, this will give you a red border around the control whenever it's in an error state.

To get the actual error message displayed requires an update to the [`Validation.ErrorTemplateProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.validation.errortemplate?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Controls_Validation_ErrorTemplate) for the control - the error text can be found by binding to `(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent`.

I've covered this, including a generic way to handle validation display (rather than writing a new style for every control type that you use), in a recent [blog post](http://peregrinesview.uk/mvvm-validation/).